# Эффект beat Jquery

Tags: jquery

Есть блок div, нужно сделать эффект "удара", когда текст быстро увеличиваться и пропорционально уменьшается, меняю цвет.

Comment: @junart, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 1):

Есть множество библиотек для реализации визуальных эффектов. Например можете поискать нужную функцию в [**Raphael**](http://raphaeljs.com/) или использовать специализированный **http://daneden.me/animate/**